# Having issue with max_norm parameter of torch.nn.Embedding

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, categorical-data, embedding, normalize

I use torch.nn.Embedding to embed my model’s categorical input features, however, I face problems when I set the max_norm parameter to not None.
There is a note on the pytorch docs page that explains how to use max_norm parameter through the following example:

```
n, d, m = 3, 5, 7
embedding = nn.Embedding(n, d, max_norm=True)
W = torch.randn((m, d), requires_grad=True)
idx = torch.tensor(\[1, 2\])
a = embedding.weight.clone() @ W.t()  # weight must be cloned for this to be differentiable
b = embedding(idx) @ W.t()  # modifies weight in-place
out = (a.unsqueeze(0) + b.unsqueeze(1))
loss = out.sigmoid().prod()
loss.backward()
```

I can’t easily understand this example from the docs. What is the purpose of having both ‘a’ and ‘b’ and why ‘out’ is defined as, `out = (a.unsqueeze(0) + b.unsqueeze(1))`?

Do we need to first clone the entire embedding tensor as in ‘a’, and then finding the embeddings for our desired indices as in ‘b’? Then how do ‘a’ and ‘b’ need to be added?

In my code, I don’t have W explicitly, I am assuming that W is representative of the weights applied by the torch.nn.Linear layers. So, I just need to prepare the input (which includes the embeddings for categorical features) that goes into my network.

I greatly appreciate any instructions on this, as understanding this example would help me adapt my code accordingly.

Comment: This example is purely illustrative. They're saying that if you want to use the embedding layer for other differential purposes, you have to clone the weights prior to calling the foward command `embedding(idx)`.  All you'd need to do in your code is set up the embedding layer and put it into your model, with the above consideration in mind in your forward call.

Answer (score 0):

Because `W` in the line computing `a` requires gradients, we must save `embedding.weight` to compute those gradients in the backward pass. However, in the line computing `b`, executing `embedding(idx)` will scale `embedding.weight` by `max_norm` - in place. So, without cloning it in line `a`, `embedding.weight` will be modified when line `b` is executed - changing what was saved for the backward pass to update `W`. Hence the requirement to clone `embedding.weight` - to save it before it gets scaled in line `b`.

If you don't use `embedding.weight` outside of the normal forward pass, you don't need to worry about all this.

If you get an error, post it (and your code).